# tinyMCE skin styles bleed over to global style scope

Tags: typescript, webpack, tinymce

got a huge issue - tinyMCE styles overwrite app (Angular 2 + Webpack 2 + TS)
styles... i'm import it like this in editor component

```
import 'tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css';
import 'tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css';
```

this issue also presented at https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/2836
and i'm try use solution from one of comments to this issue,

```
require.context(
  'file?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=node_modules/tinymce!tinymce/skins', 
  true, 
  /.*/
)
```

but got ts error,

> Property 'context' does not exist on type 'NodeRequire'

maybe someone know another way, how implement styles for this editor and don't touch main app styles...

Comment: Few years old, but for others in same boat, we also have this issue, in 2020. I wonder if loading the styles via skin_url is somehow scoping the css, and by loading it with webpack imports, we are putting it on global. I had issues getting skin_url to work properly together with dynamic chunks though.